# How do I place a button at the end of the text in a UITextView?

Tags: ios

I can't really think of a way on how to put a custom `UIButton` at the end of the text of the `UITextView`. Not its trailing ending, not its frame, but its text.

If only I could use `UILabel`, then I could just implement this functionality using `TTTAttributedLabel`.

My goal is just like that, not just a simple hide/show READ MORE functionality or whatsoever.

---

Here's the goal:

[image]

---

And here's a simple code, I'm using frame for now for some experiments instead of constraints - and besides, I can't see the use of constraints if I don't even know where to constraint the button.

```
 UIImage *toggleDescriptionFieldButtonImage = self.isFieldDescriptionShown ?
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_field_desc_shown"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_field_desc_hidden"];
  
  toggleDesciptionFieldButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  toggleDesciptionFieldButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25);
  [toggleDesciptionFieldButton setImage:toggleDescriptionFieldButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [toggleDesciptionFieldButton addTarget:self
                                  action:@selector(toggleDescriptionFieldPressed:)
                        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Is the UITextView within a UITableViewCell or UICollectionViewCell? Maybe you could add a UITextView and a UIButton in a cell, create AutoLayout constraints so the button is always at the side of the UITextView and make it resize accordingly to its intrinsic height and width

Comment: Yes, the textView is within a cell. And no, I don't think that would work. What that will do is put the button at the trailing frame of the textView and not the frame of the text. Suppose if you have 100 pt width of textView and its text is just one word that consumes say 50pt, then you would have an extra 50pt spacing.